# Solve $\eta_{xx}-w\eta_x=0$ where $\eta(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am solving a system of equations.
These are the two equations I have solved:

\begin{align}
\eta_{xx}-w\eta_x&=0\\
\eta(x,y) &= a(y) + b(y)e^{wx}\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\xi_{yy}-\frac{1}{y}\xi_y&= 0\\
y^2\xi_{yy} - y\xi_y &= 0\\
\xi(x,y)&= d(x) + f(x)y^2\\
\end{align}

Is this correct?

Comment: @Satyendra sorry, typo, thanks I fixed it.

Comment: All you have to do is substitute in your candidates and see how they work out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first PDE I got this:
$$\eta_{xx}-w\eta_x=0$$
$$\eta_{x}-w\eta=C_1$$
$$(e^{-wx}\eta )'=C_1e^{-wx}$$
$$e^{-wx}\eta =-\dfrac {C_1}we^{-wx}+C_2$$
$$\eta =e^{wx}(-\dfrac {C_1}we^{-wx}+C_2)$$
$$\eta (x,y) ={C(y)}+C_2(y)e^{wx}$$
For the second PDE:
$$\xi_{yy}-\frac{1}{y}\xi_y= 0$$
$$y\xi_{yy}-\xi_y= 0$$
$$\left(\dfrac { \xi_y} y \right)'=0$$
$$ \xi_y =C_1y$$
$$ \xi =Cy^2+C_2$$
$$ \xi (x,y) =C(x)y^2+C_2(x)$$
So everything is correct.